# Excel VBA - color data labels ("value from cells") according to the font of the source

Tags: vba, excel

I have to run many bar charts in excel 2016, each one showing the company performance over the seasons, for a certain country. On top of each bar I'd like to see the %Change in this format [Color10]0%"▲";[Red] -0%"▼". Reason why I added the data labels, and I used the function "value from cells" to show the %Change instead of the amount sold. Now everything is in place, and my percentages are nicely placed on top of the bars, but no way I can color them automatically (positive green and negative red). I tried formatting the labels directly from the format window placed under "numbers", but I discovered it doesn't work at all when the label content is derived using "value from cells".

So I started looking into VBA, but since I'm pretty ignorant about programming, I didn't succeed. I'm looking for a code that changes the data labels of my chart so that they maintain the font of the source (in the source my %Change values are already in the desired format ([Color10]0%"▲";[Red] -0%"▼"). Googling I found different solutions but none worked. I'll post the ones I that look better to me.

```
Sub legend_color()
Dim SRS As Series
With ActiveChart
For Each SRS In .SeriesCollection
SRS.ApplyDataLabels AutoText:=True, LegendKey:= _False, 
ShowSeriesName:=False, 
ShowCategoryName:=False, 
ShowValue:=True, _ ShowPercentage:=False, 
ShowBubbleSize:=False
SRS.DataLabels.Font.ColorIndex = SRS.Border.ColorIndex
Next SRS
End With
End Sub
```

This one was the only one that actually run, and colored my labels all white. With the following I run into errors.

```
    Sub color_labels()
        Dim chartIterator As Integer, 
        pointIterator As Integer, _seriesArray() As Variant

        For chartIterator = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
              seriesArray=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values For pointIterator = 1 To UBound(seriesArray)
If seriesArray(pointIterator) >= 0 Then
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _
Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _RGB(146, 208, 80)
Else
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(chartIterator). _Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = _RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
Next pointIterator
Next chartIterator
End Sub


Sub ArrowColour()
Dim ncars As Integer
ncars = Range("A1").Value
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Down Arrow 1")).Fill
If ncars > 0 Then

.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)

Else

.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End If

End With
End Sub


Option Explicit
Sub ApplyCustomLabels()
Dim rLabels As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim oSeries As Series
Dim Cnt As Integer
Set rLabels = Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
Set oSeries = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)  
oSeries.HasDataLabels = True
Cnt = 1
For Each rCell In rLabels
With oSeries.Points(Cnt).DataLabel.Text = rCell.Value.Font.Color =rCell.Font.Color
End With
Cnt = Cnt + 1
Next rCell
End Sub
```

Thank you very much in advance for all of your help,
Tommaso

Comment: What errors do you run into?. The first took the cokour of your borders, so that most likely is white/transparent.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!** Check out the [tour] (you'll earn a badge!) and also [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic here.  Here's important info about **how to create a [mcve]** and some other asking-tips to  get you started and help get your question some attention: see "[ask]" as well as tips [**here**](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [**here**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/) Plus, here's the [**Formatting FAQ**](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just missing the colors then you can format each label using something like:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim s As Series, dl As DataLabels, d As DataLabel
    Dim i As Long, rngLabels

    Set s = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

    Set dl = s.DataLabels

    'Option 1: set label color based on label value
    For i = 1 To dl.Count
        With dl(i)
            .Font.Color = IIf(Val(.Text) < 0, vbRed, vbGreen)
        End With
    Next i


    'Option 2: set label color based on label source cell
    '  Note use of DisplayFormat to pick up custom
    '   formatting colors
    Set rngLabels = Range("C7:C13")'<< source range for data labels
    For i = 1 To dl.Count
        dl(i).Font.Color = rngLabels(i).DisplayFormat.Font.Color
    Next i
End Sub
```